# adding the quantity to the shardepreference list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, increment, decrement

I have two activity first is products where there is button to increment and decrements each product, and the second is a cart that displays products populated from the `sharedPrefrence` list in the first activity,the counter is working fine, But i don't how to add the quantity of each product to the `sharedPreference` list, Both activities are `recycleViews`

**this is my first activity adapter class**

```
public class productsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<productsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    public List<products> productList;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    int quantity;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count, quantity;
        public ImageView thumbnail, cart, inc, dec;
        private Context context;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {


            super(view);

            context = itemView.getContext();
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            cart = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart);
            inc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
            dec = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);


        }
    }


    public productsAdapter(Context mContext, List<products> productList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.products_card, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final products p = productList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(p.getName());
        holder.count.setText(p.getPrice() + "L.E");
        Glide.with(mContext).load(p.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
        holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(p.getQuantity()));
        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), product_details.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("img", p.getThumbnail());
                bundle.putString("name", p.getName());
                bundle.putInt("price", p.getPrice());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        holder.cart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cart_black_24dp);


        holder.cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
                sharedPreference.addFavorite(mContext, productList.get(position));
                holder.cart.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_cart);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "تم الاضافة للسلة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.cart.setClickable(false);

            }
        });
        quantity =0;
        holder.inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantity = p.getQuantity()+1 ;
                p.setQuantity(quantity);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.v("current quantity", String.valueOf(quantity));
            }
        });

        holder.dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                quantity = p.getQuantity()-1;
                p.setQuantity(quantity);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }


    public int getItemCount() {

        return productList.size();
    }

    public void setfilter(ArrayList<products> newlist) {
        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.addAll(newlist);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        ;
    }
   }
```

**the main for first activity**

```
public class ell2lban extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    productsAdapter adapter;
    List<products> List;
    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "product_list";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ell2lban);
        List = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(ell2lban.this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ell2lban.GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        adapter = new productsAdapter(ell2lban.this, List);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(300);

        new BooksAsyns().execute();
    }


    private class BooksAsyns extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(ell2lban.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String JsonResponse = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                // Enter URL address where your json file resides
                // Even you can make call to php file which returns json data
                url = new URL("http://192.168.1.13//grad/category1.php");


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
//                conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0(compatible)");
//                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
                // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
//                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(input, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);


                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method

                }
                JsonResponse = result.toString().trim();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                return JsonResponse;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;

        }







        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pdLoading.dismiss();


            try {


                JSONArray itmes = new JSONArray(s);
                for (int i = 0; i < itmes.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject subObject = itmes.getJSONObject(i);
                    String NAME = subObject.getString("NAME");
                    int price = subObject.getInt("PRICE");
                    String img = subObject.getString("PICTURE");

                    List.add(new products(NAME,img,price));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        private int spanCount;
        private int spacing;
        private boolean includeEdge;

        public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
            this.spanCount = spanCount;
            this.spacing = spacing;
            this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
            int column = position % spanCount; // item column

            if (includeEdge) {
                outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

                if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                    outRect.top = spacing;
                }
                outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
            } else {
                outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
                outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
                if (position >= spanCount) {
                    outRect.top = spacing; // item top
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

}
```

**second activity adapter**

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder> {
    List<products> adapterlist = new ArrayList<>();
    CartActivity cartactivity;
    Context cnx;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    public CartAdapter(List<products> adapterlist, Context cnx) {
        this.adapterlist = adapterlist;
        this.cnx = cnx;
        cartactivity = (CartActivity) cnx;
    }

    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_cards, parent, false);
        CartViewHolder cartviewholder = new CartViewHolder(v, cartactivity);

        return cartviewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CartViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final products p = adapterlist.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(p.getName());
        holder.price.setText(p.getPrice() + "L.E");
        holder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(p.getQuantity()));
        Glide.with(cnx).load(p.getThumbnail()).into(holder.image);

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreference sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
                adapterlist.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                sharedPreference.saveFavorites(cnx, adapterlist);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
        Log.v("Quantity",String.valueOf(p));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapterlist.size();
    }


    public static class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView price, name,quantity;
        Button button;
        CartActivity cartactivity;
        CardView cardv;

        public CartViewHolder(View itemView, CartActivity cartactivity) {
            super(itemView);
            this.cartactivity = cartactivity;

            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartimage);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pn);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(p);
            button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            cardv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardd);
            quantity=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity)   ;
        }

    }

}
```

**second activity main**

```
        public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button l;
        ImageView imv;
        Toolbar t;
        RecyclerView rv;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager;
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        List<products> cartitems;
        ArrayList<products> selected_items_list = new ArrayList<>();
        SharedPreference sharedPreference;

        public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
        int countt = 0;
        boolean edit_mode = false;
        TextView counterr;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);


            sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
            cartitems = sharedPreference.getFavorites(CartActivity.this);
            if (cartitems == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, test.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {

                if (cartitems.size() == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, test.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
            if (cartitems != null) {
                rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mycartrecycler);
                layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
                rv.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                adapter = new CartAdapter(cartitems, CartActivity.this);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);


            }


        } }
```

Comment: I believe there is a logical problem with your whole project, Please try to use `localdatabase` for your project instead of `sharedPrefrence`, and please be more specific in your question.

Comment: is there isn't anyway to do it without local database?

Comment: You should define the issue correctly, so we can help.